# Volcano plot R -how to show the top hits

Tags: r, label, scatter-plot

I am having some trouble in showing my top 10 dysregulated genes on the volcano plot by using R.
I am trying to learn so please be kind =D I am sure it is quite easy...

I tried different ways as found on internet:

1. For creating a new colomn called "delabel" and assigning my gene names from the "id" column I used:

```
proteomics_P_value$delabel <- ifelse(proteomics_P_value$id %in% head(proteomics_P_value[order(proteomics_P_value$Log2FC), "id"], 10), proteomics_P_value$id, NA)
```

However, when I checked, I just have "NA" with any gene names anywhere.

2. I tried to create a thresh using:

```
thresh=head(arrange(proteomics_P_value, -Log10value), 10)$Log10Pvalue[10]
head(arrange(proteomics_P_value, -Log10Pvalue), 10)$Log10Pvalue[10] *#I checked and it was ok*
head(arrange(proteomics_P_value, -Log10Pvalue), 10)$id *#I checked and it was ok
proteomics_P_value$delabel[proteomics_P_value$Log10Pvalue <=thresh] <- (proteomics_P_value$id[proteomics_P_value<=thresh]) 

# Here I get an error: 
Error in proteomics_P_value$delabel[proteomics_P_value$Log10Pvalue <=  : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments*
```

3. Then I used geom_label_repel trying to putting a filter. While it gives me some labels, they are not the right ones as specified in the filter.

```
ggplot(proteomics_P_value, aes(x = Log2FC, y = Log10Pvalue, col = expression)) + geom_point(alpha= 0.3, size = 2, shape=16) + geom_hline(yintercept= 2 , linetype="dashed") + theme_classic(base_size = 18) + scale_color_manual(values = c('blue1', 'azure3', 'brown2')) + geom_vline(xintercept = c(-0.156, 0.157), linetype="dashed") + labs (title = "Proteomics day2") + easy_center_title() + geom_label_repel(proteomics_P_value=filter(proteomics_P_value, "Log10Pvalue" >= 2.23), aes(label=id))  
Warning messages:  
1: ggrepel: 7608 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
2: ggrepel: 7608 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps 
3: In geom_label_repel(proteomics_P_value = filter(proteomics_P_value,  :
  Ignoring unknown parameters: `proteomics_P_value`
4: Removed 26 rows containing missing values (`geom_point()`). 
5: Removed 26 rows containing missing values (`geom_label_repel()`). 
6: ggrepel: 7608 unlabeled data points (too many overlaps). Consider increasing max.overlaps
```

Many thanks!!!